# Expected Probability using Indicator Random Variable

Tags: probability

Consider a collection of 9 bears. There is a family of red bears consisting of one father bear, one mother bear, and one baby bear. There is a similar green bear family, and a similar blue bear family. We draw 5 consecutive times from this collection without replacement (i.e., not returning the bear after each draw). We keep track (in order) of the kind of bears that we get. Let X denote the number of red bears selected.

**8a.** For i = 1,2,3,4,5 , let X = 1 if the i<sup>th</sup> bear selected is red, and X<sub>i</sub>=0 otherwise. So we have X = X<sub>1</sub>+X<sub>2</sub>+X<sub>3</sub>+X<sub>4</sub>+X<sub>5</sub>. Find E(X<sub>i</sub>) for i = 1,2,3,4,5, and then find E(X).

**8b.** Refer to the red father bear as red bear #1, and the red mother bear as red bear #2, and the red baby bear as red bear #3. For i = 1,2,3,4,5, let Y<sub>i</sub>=1 if the i<sup>th</sup> red bear is selected (at any time, i.e., on any of the five selections), and Y<sub>i</sub>=0 otherwise. So we have X = Y<sub>1</sub>+Y<sub>2</sub>+Y<sub>3</sub>. Find E(Y<sub>i</sub>) for i = 1,2,3 , and then find E(X).

Now, For the part 8a:
X<sub>1</sub>=3/9 = 1/3 That's easy but the problem is, I can't find the logic for other X<sub>i</sub>'s I tried combination as well, it didn't work.

Solution:
For reference the solution for 8a: 
E(X) = E(X<sub>1</sub>)+E(X<sub>2</sub>)+E(X<sub>3</sub>)+E(X<sub>4</sub>)+E(X<sub>5</sub>)

E(X<sub>i</sub>)'s are all 1/3 [I want to know how]
so, E(X) = 5/3

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For 8a, symmetry guarantees $E(X_i) = 1/3$ for all $i.$ Then linearity tells you what $E(X)$ is.

Comment: Thanks, I see now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *Totat Probability Theorem* as follows

$E(X_{2}) = \Pr(\text{the second bear is red}) = Pr(\text{the second bear is red} | \text{the first bear is red})Pr(\text{the first bear be red}) + Pr(\text{the second bear is red} | \text{the first bear is not red})Pr(\text{the first bear is not red}) = \frac{2}{8}*\frac{3}{9} + \frac{3}{8}*\frac{6}{9}$

For $X_{i}, 3\leq i\leq 5$,  do the same way...

Comment: @ShailendraPatel I don't see how this is not 'the way it as been asked in the question' since all the question asks is that you compute the $E(X_i).$ This gives $E(X_2)=1/3$ and gives a blueprint for showing the rest of them are $1/3$, although as I mentioned in the comments the fact that they are all $1/3$ follows more simply from symmetry (how could red be more or less likely than blue or green at any draw?).

Comment: Yes, I see. Since, X_1 and X_2 are 1/3, is that enough to prove all others will be 1/3?

Comment: @ShailendraPatel No.. Hasan's calculation shows $E(X_2)=1/3$. It can be generalized to calculate that all others are $1/3$ but does not in and of itself imply that they all are. The symmetry argument, on the other hand, shows directly that they all are. BTW to communicate on here you need to reply with @ like I did to you. I wouldn't have seen your reply if I hadn't kept this page open in my browser.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I did the question using the total probability method that Hasan used but it takes some time to evaluate, the main reason why I posted this question was to know if there's a better method or if I am doing anything wrong. Thanks for the help! Both of you.